# Determining outcome of jquery dialog. Assigning outcome of dialog to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

You can use dialog boxed to return a variable in javascript, such as:

```
//sets variable as false
var shouldIngest = false; 
//depends if cancel, ok, or the "x" is clicked
shouldIngest = confirm("Do you want to ingest?");

if( shouldIngest ) {
    //do some things...
}else{
   //do something else...
}
```

I want to use the [jQuery UI dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) so I can customize / style the confirm box a little. How can I achieve the same with the jQuery UI dialog? I want to capture the outcome of the dialog for `var shouldIngest`. The code below doesn't seem to work.

```
var shouldIngest = false;

$('#ingestConfirmDialog').html('Do you want to Ingest this document into the form?');
shouldIngest = $('#ingestConfirmDialog').dialog({
    modal : true,
    draggable : false,
    buttons : {
        "Yes Ingest this Docx" : function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");    
        },
       "Just Add as Attachment" : function () {
           $(this).dialog("close");
       }
   }
```

});

What can I do to fix this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just put the code you want to run for "yes" and "no" inside those button callback functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the variable in the button callbacks:

```
buttons : {
    "Yes Ingest this Docx" : function () {
        shouldIngest = true;
        $(this).dialog("close");    
    },
    "Just Add as Attachment" : function () {
        shouldIngest = false;
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
 }
```

Or, since you use the buttons to determine whether you should perform some action, just skip setting the flag and just perform the action:

```
buttons : {
    "Yes Ingest this Docx" : function () {
        callYouIngestionMethod();
        $(this).dialog("close");    
    },
    "Just Add as Attachment" : function () {
       // just close the dialog            
       $(this).dialog("close");
    }
 }
```